# How is the info in the package.xml of a metapackage used?

Tags: ros, catkin, package.xml, metapackage, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that one of the usage is to let buildfarm know which pkgs in the given metapkg to be built.

---

From here is just fyi of what makes me wonder about this.

I know 1 of the pkgs in my metapkg that I'm trying to release into `hydro` doesn't build yet since one of the dependent pkgs is not yet available in the buildfarm. Actually `bloom-release`ing doesn't proceed at its internal `rosdep` call. In an attempt to tell the buildfarm not to build this single pkg "A-a" that depends on not-yet-available pkg, I commented out a `run_depend` entry of "A-a" in `package.xml` of the metapkg. But `bloom` still doesn't let me push it [0].

Am I doing something wrong with `package.xml`? What is the recommended usage of ROS tools (eg. `bloom`, `package.xml` etc) to release a metapkg that some of its components don't build?

I know I can make a temporary branch on my `vcs` tool locally but particularly I want to know how the information in `package.xml` in metapkg is used. Thanks!

---

[0] Upon `bloom-release`ing a metapkg, I get:

```
Could not resolve rosdep key 'foo'
Resolve problem with rosdep and then continue to try again.
Continue [Y/n]? Y
Running 'rosdep update'...
Could not resolve rosdep key 'foo'
Resolve problem with rosdep and then continue to try again.
Continue [Y/n]? n
```

[1] the depended pkg is not available yet:

```
$ rosdep --rosdistro hydro resolve foo
ERROR: no rosdep rule for 'foo'
```

Btw, `foo` here is `tf2_ros`. I'm trying to generalize the issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61870/how-is-the-info-in-the-package.xml-of-a-metapackage-used?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-30**:
A metapackage need not necessarily be contained within the same repo as the packages on which it depends. Your question seems to assume that they are all released together, which is often done.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-01**:
@Dirk Thomas your comment sounds like an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The dependencies of a metapackage only effect the debian package generated for that metapackage. It does not "disable" the other package when you comment out the line.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0